# How will I know, if two nodes are somehow connected in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that depicts node and their relationships, Entity - References - Entity.

I want to get a list containing Source Entity and Connected Entity where these two entities are not directly connected but are connected somehow.

For Example : 
a - references -b , c - references - a, d - references - c. In this case, I also want the Cypher Qry to return d - references - a.

The Output I would like is :

a-b

c-a

d-c

c-b

d-a

d-b

Answer (score 0):

Cypher is primarily about pattern matching in graphs. So the pattern you are interested in would cover not only `a-b` but also `a-c-d`. You can do this using a variable length match, e.g.:

```
MATCH (n)-[*]-(m)
RETURN n.name, m.name
```

This assumes there is a name property on the nodes, which can be returned. Change that for any other relevant property, or just `RETURN n, m` if you're using the browser for visualization.

Note that this will match relationships regardless of direction, which means you'll get both `a-d` and `d-a` in the result (and every other combination). If you want to match with just one direction, use:

```
MATCH (n)-[*]->(m)
RETURN n.name, m.name
```

**Be careful with these approaches - even in small graphs, they could easily end up matching a huge number of combinations** and cause Neo4j, or your application, to die (due to memory exhaustion, etc).

Comment: Thanks Chris. the keyword references in the use case I had provided refers to a relation which has a property value 'REFERENCES'. while the graph will have a lot of other links , Im worried at extracting only those relations that have an attribute named 'RelType' and which have a Value 'REFERENCES'. Yes you are right, if I have this unchecked the result will quickly grow. So Direction is also mandatory in my query. The Challenge is I was not able to merge *1..5 and a Relation Name in the [ r ] clause even assuming a max of 5 level indirection. Any help in this regard will be great.

Comment: Try `MATCH (n)-[:REFERENCES*1..5]->(m)`

Comment: Is there a way to get the number of relations along with this nodes? Like id a-> x, a->y, b->x, b->y then a and b are connected and count as 2

Comment: @gjijo Best to ask that as a new question